# Modelling proportion data using GLMMs

Tags: mixed-model, generalized-linear-model, random-effects-model, glmm

I am having some trouble finding the correct way to analyse some data.

I am trying to determine whether a certain treatment had an effect on frog calling.
Frog calling was measured as presence or absence every minute over 3 hours under control and treatment conditions.
The study was done at 9 sites over 11 different nights in a 2 week period. Not all sites have data for all nights.

I have tried modelling this data as 'Proportion' data (each 3 hour period condensed down to proportion of minutes calling).

My data are structured like this:

```r
  Site     Date Treatment Proportion   w 
1    2 20180117   Control      1.000 180 
2    8 20180117   Control      0.922 180 
3    4 20180118   Control      0.000 180 
4    5 20180118   Control      0.911 180 
5    2 20180119   Control      1.000 180 
6    8 20180119   Control      0.994 180
... 
41   5 20180126      Lure      0.983 180
42   9 20180126      Lure      0.994 180
43   7 20180127      Lure      0.966 180
44   8 20180127      Lure      0.850 180
45   9 20180129      Lure      0.005 180
46   1 20180130      Lure      1.000 180
```

I have tried modelling this using a binomial GLMM such as below:

```r
model <- glmer(Proportion ~ Treatment + (1 | Site) + (1 | Date), 
               data = data, 
               weights = w,
               family = binomial())
```

However, I am uncertain whether this is correct. I am using weights = 180 (i.e., number of minutes proportion was calculated from) 
but this seems wrong in this instance as each of those minutes are highly correlated with one another and are from the same trial rather than from individual trials.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of points:

- It seems to me that you could your outcome as a count, i.e., the number of frog callings in a three hours period. Hence, you could fit a mixed effects Poisson or negative binomial models (the latter accounts for over-dispersion). These are, for example, provided by the [**GLMMadaptive**](https://drizopoulos.github.io/GLMMadaptive/) package I have written; you can find several examples under *Articles*.
- By including a random intercept per `Date` you postulate that frog callings from different sites on the same data are correlated. In case you want instead to assume that frog callings within a site are more correlated when they are closer in time, then you would need a random slope, e.g., `(days | Site)` where `days` denotes the number of days from the start of the experiment.

Comment: Thank you very much for responding.

I tried using your GLMMadaptive package however I think I need still need two grouping factors in my model (Site and Date), which GLMMadaptive can't currently do? The reason is treatment was also manipulated 'within' Site so that each Site received control or treatment on different nights. I do assume that frog callings from different sites on the same date may be correlated (e.g. due to environmental conditions).

Comment: I have tried fitting models (using poisson, nbinom1 and nbinom2) to count data now instead of proportion data using glmmTMB package. Is this suitable if my 'count' data is constrained by # of mins (i.e. 180)?

Comment: Yes, it is suitable.